# Mail is not sent every time by swiftmailer using office365

Tags: php, smtp, office365, swiftmailer

Smtp details which we use are correct, for host smtp.office365.com mail is not sent every time.

Sometimes this error is generated,
Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "XXX" using 2 possible authenticators in vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php on line 181

**Observed behaviour**

Sometimes with the same details, emails are sent.

**Expected behaviour**

It should send an email every time.

Can anyone please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is the login credentials you used correct and the.env file configured correctly? Here are two links that might be useful to you.

[PHP Fatal error: 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663783/php-fatal-error-swift-transportexception-with-message-failed-to-authenticate)

[Failed to authenticate on SMTP server error using gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939393/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-error-using-gmail/33939635)

Comment: Yes, everything is correct. Mail is sent sometimes. But fails most of the time.