# Getting error "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username" on Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I'm implementing email sending portal with laravel but it is giving me an error which is given below :

```
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v21sm1478030pjy.3 - gsmtp
". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v21sm1478030pjy.3 - gsmtp
". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v21sm1478030pjy.3 - gsmtp
".
```

Comment: check your credential again in .env file or paste your .env file mail section here. did you using gmail mail?.If yes Did you generate api key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to authenticate on SMTP server error using gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939393/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-error-using-gmail)

Comment: I've changed my email security and now it's working fine for me. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have `2-Step Verification` turned ***ON*** with the account you're using and then login the email account on your browser then [click this](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) link to allow less secure apps to connect to your GMail Account.

Comment: @SoftTechnoes cheers bud. Please upvote if it solved your problem.