# Laravel - How to fix "failed to authenticate on SMTP server" in Laravel 8 and Office365?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, office365

In one of my Laravel 8 based applications, I want to switch from Mailgun to Office365 as a service change. Here is the information I have to integrate:

```
SMTP hostname: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: STARTTLS
SSL Protocol: OFF
TLS Protocol: ON
SMTP Username: smtp_user_email
SMTP Password: smtp_password
```

So I write the following code in my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=smtp_user_email
MAIL_PASSWORD=smtp_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=smtp_user_email
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Then test the default `Forget Password` form of Laravel (so there should be no issue related to that form as it is the standard form of Laravel). But I receive the following response:

> Swift_TransportException
> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "smtp_user_email" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [SI2PR02CA0047.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com] ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SI2PR02CA0047.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com] ".

I check the username and password, which is OK but I have no idea why it returns authenticationon related error!

Does anyone why actually I missing that returns the error?

- Thanks

Comment: Use double quote for password

Comment: But there is no special character & it is still returned the same error!

Comment: I'm just giving suggestions. It's up to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939635/984422

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to authenticate on SMTP server error using gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939393/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-error-using-gmail)