# SMTP Gmail in Laravel

Tags: laravel

my app used to be working fine . I can send email through my app using config in my laravel `env` file .

Later this week, the app won't send any email . I tried looking for the reason and I found that Google stopped or changed the way it should be.

I tried the following in my `env` :

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME=xxxxx
```

The solution I tried is this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939393/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-error-using-gmail)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution . You have to activate Two-Factor Auth. Then you can generate a new App Password .
Place the generated password in the `env` file inside double quotes `"generatedpassword"`